# Выделение памяти без инициализации с помощью оператора new

Tags: c++, malloc

Возможно ли с помощью оператора `new` сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
class MyData {
    char data[1024];
    MyData() {}
};

MyData* dataArray = static_cast<MyData*>(malloc(10 * sizeof(MyData)));
```

Т.е. выделить память под объект или массив объектов без ее инициализации?

Comment: Пуркуа бы и не па? при использовании можно воспользоваться размещающим `new`. Только лучше, пожалуй, в С++ использовать не `malloc`, а `new char[...]`

Comment: @Harry, а почему? `new char[...]` заполняет нулями, правильно понимаю?

Comment: Нет, но просто `malloc` - это все же C, а не C++.  Другая идеология :)

Comment: @Abyx А не подскажете, как в `vector` эту проблему обходят? Они же не создают все элементы сразу - для `vector` наличие конструктора по умолчанию, насколько я помню, не обязательно? Как они резервируют память?

Comment: @Harry, ну там явно не приводят тип. Выделили буфер аллокатором, и делают в него placement new. Но мне интересно, является ли такой каст ub. С одной стороны ничего криминального, а с другой явного разрешения aliasing-а `viod*` я не нашел(плохо искал?)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Выделили. как что? Как `new char[]`, грубо говоря? Пусть. Разместили - опять же можно без приведения. Но как обратиться? Например, `at()` возвращает ссылку - как вы ее без приведения вернете? Да просто деструктор вызвать - а его придется вызывать явно - как? Все равно придется пояснять, что по этому адресу находится объект данного типа - т.е. без приведения типа не обойтись?

Comment: @Harry, ну placement new же принимает `void*`, а возвращает `T*`. Можно [как-то так](http://cpp.sh/5ggca) сделать. Хотя признаю, это немного замудрено, с кастами было бы проще. Но я никак не могу найти можно ли безопасно кастовать результат `malloc` к произвольному типу или нет. В C это приведение вообще автоматически выполняется и считается безопасным. Почему вдруг @Abyx классифицировал его как UB ума не приложу

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Да вот я тоже никак не пойму, реализация вектора в стандартной библиотеке - UB или не UB... Я понимаю, что получить *реальные* неприятности от strict aliasing - это надо очень извратиться... но, тем не менее, с точки зрения буквы стандарта - это UB или нет?...

Comment: @Abyx, там нет UB, там всё нормально. Преобразование в `void*` и обратно не даёт UB само по себе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно. Можно использовать тот же `malloc`, а можно использовать `operator new` (или `operator new[]`), который выделит кусок "сырой" памяти.
Отличие `operator new` от `operator new[]` - фактически в том, 
что можно более эффективнее реализовать собственные версии этих операторов.
Так что всё, что сказано про `operator new`, относится и к `operator new[]`.

`operator new` также запрашивает непрерывный кусок памяти, 
и возвращает указатель на "нечто" (`void*`).
Никакие конструкторы эта штуковина тоже не вызывает,
но уже знает о исключениях и если выделение не удастся,
то, кинет исключение, а не вернет `nullptr` (хотя это не всегда выполняется). На самом деле, 
сначала еще попытает счастье с `new_handler`, но опустим этот момент.
Также есть версия, которая не кидает исключение, а возвращает `nullptr` в случае неудачи и версия, которая совсем не выделяет память, а просто параметр-указатель проходит там "транзитом" (такая версия используется для *placement new*), причем можно еще и перегружать `operator new`, но сейчас не об этом.

Для освобождения памяти, выделенной с помощью `operator new`, используется `operator delete`.

Для освобождения памяти, выделенной с помощью `operator new[]`, используется `operator delete[]`.

```
void *p = operator new(sizeof(T) * count);
operator delete (p);
```

Вызвать конструкторы для инициализации можно с помощью *placement new*:

```
T *pT = new (p) T[count];
```

Конечно же, при таком подходе вызов конструкторов и деструкторов целиком на авторе кода.